# My HTML <a> tag is not showing the title attribute

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, tags

Should the title attribute work in a  tag?, I have this one:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="confirmation" 
data-title="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar?" id="confirmation" 
data-btnOkLabel="Sí" data-btnCancelLabel="No" data-btnCancelClass="borde"
data-href="Evento_controlador.php?del={$evento.id}" 
title="Borrar" name="ver_evento2"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

And its not showing the title information. I don't know why.

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: ok, edited. do you know an attribute that can do the same as the title in a <a> tag? @JohnConde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have something to display *inside* of A tag. For example add TEST TEXT:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="confirmation" 
data-title="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar?" id="confirmation" 
data-btnOkLabel="Sí" data-btnCancelLabel="No" data-btnCancelClass="borde"
data-href="Evento_controlador.php?del={$evento.id}" 
title="Borrar" name="ver_evento2"><i class="icon-remove">Test Text</i></a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JftrA/

Title is a tooltip that will be displayed when you hover over that text.

*UPDATE*:  With a **correct CSS** you do not need content inside of A tag. For example:

```
.icon-remove {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JftrA/2/

Make sure your CSS is correct.

Comment: oh thank you, but i only wanted to show that icon in the <i> tag, and no text. Is it possible? @YuriyGalanter

Comment: He has something, that `<i>` element probably has a size and a background with some icon.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, i added the title attribute to the <i> tag and it worked. Thank you @YuriyGalanter